# Dotnetnuke Module Development roadblocks, where is my module?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dotnetnuke

I've been trying to wrap my head around module development for DotNetNuke for the past day and I keep running into roadblocks.  Prior to this, being the *NIX/OSX grognard that I am, I have managed to create a Skin and a few Widgets "The Hard Way" by creating the manifest file myself with a python script, coding everything in Textmate and using a Makefile to create the packages anytime I update it, then installing it onto a remote development site on some shared hosting.  However, I want to try things the "DotNetNuke way", so I've been looking around for instructions now that I've got a Windows VM up and running.

From what I've found, this is what you're actually supposed to do:

1. Create a local dotnetnuke website.
2. When the dotnetnuke website has been created, go to Host -> Extensions -> Create Extension
3. Select Module and fill out all the forms.
4. Open up the website in Visual Studio.
5. Find your module in the <site>/DesktopModules and start hacking away at it
6. When you want to redistribute your package, go to Host -> Extensions -> Edit Module -> Create Package.

There are a couple of problems with this, however.  I get as far as step 5, and for some reason I can't seem to find my module in DesktopModules.  I have tried looking elsewhere in the directory tree for my test module and I can't find it anywhere.  In addition, when I try editing a package, I can't see any "Create Package" button.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?  I'm using the absolute latest DotNetNuke as of this writing (5.6.0), by the way.

**Update:** Okay, feeling a little foolish I first have to create the module in Visual Studio, then create the module in the website and attach it to the manifest of my module.  However, when I do this, my site blows up because it seems to assume that I'm using a company name of "YourCompany".  Fine.  I revert, delete the module and try again but creating my module with a namespace of my company name doesn't seem to change any "YourCompany" names, they're still all over the created files.  What in the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a search and replace in the entire project as well as the settings in the Projects settings. Also here is a link that may help [link](http://www.adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/dnn_module4/)

Comment: This ended up helping me out the most.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the project/solution properties under application make sure root  namespace is not YourCompany